# How to measure the width (in pixels) of an HTML string in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Do you know if there is such a function for HTML strings (for given size and font)?
Do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: Not a function, but there's a way. You can find it with Google (I already found it, but I don't remember the name of the site).

Comment: OK, thank you, @Stéphane Laurent.
Does it involve HTML, JavaScript?